# Retreving Data from XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<Vehicle>
  <CheckPoints ID="11">
    <Days Day="1">check</Days>
  </CheckPoints>
  <CheckPoints ID="10">
    <Days Day="1">check</Days>
  </CheckPoints>
</Vehicle>
```

and i want to query record using LINQ.
My question is, i want to iterate to each node and Match the CheckPoints Id with my Id and then want to get the Days text up to the current day. (Each CheckPoints will have Max 31 Days node as according to the Month which is going on).
Please help.

Comment: Linq-To-XML:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: can u tell me vice verse of this finding the CheckPoints with ID and write a new Node of Days with text in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var xmlstr = @"<Vehicle>  <CheckPoints ID=""11"">    <Days Day=""1"">check</Days>  </CheckPoints>  <CheckPoints ID=""11"">    <Days Day=""2"">check</Days>  </CheckPoints><CheckPoints ID=""10"">    <Days Day=""1"">check</Days>  </CheckPoints></Vehicle>";
var id=11;
var currDay = DateTime.Now.Day;
var xl = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
var resxml = from el in xl.Descendants("CheckPoints")
             where Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("ID").Value) == id
             select el into x
             from ell in x.Descendants("Days")
             where Convert.ToInt32(ell.Attribute("Day").Value) <= currDay
             select ell;

foreach (var xres in resxml)
{
    Console.Write(xres.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example. But i need till date data.Like if today is 5th then i need till date 5 data from xml as there will be 5 nodes in each CheckPoints

Comment: @Nipun, "ell.Attribute("Day").Value) <= currDay" picks all the data till today.... you can run this and check...

Comment: can u tell me vice verse of this finding the CheckPoints with ID and write a new Node of Days with text in it? i mean to say is i want to write in the resxml with the specified value in it